# How can I create a MappingModel using pydantic?

Tags: pydantic

I am trying to use pydantic in order to create a JSON schema that would validate a generic mapping, something where I can have **any key** as string and each key can have any value assigned to it.

How can I do this?

So far I was successful in using BaseModel to create models for mappings where I know each key name and type, but in this case it should be any key as long is text (or follows a regex pattern for naming), without restrictions on the value assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your case, but maybe a [custom root type](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#rootmodel-and-custom-root-types) is what you need. Something like this:

```py
from typing import Dict, Any
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Model(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[str, Any]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__root__)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self.__root__[item]


m = Model.parse_obj({'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'})
assert m.key1 == "val1"
```